# storing index in state on click , strange behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, store

I'm mapping an array, and displaying them as a button. When users clicks on button i'm storing index and displaying data depending on that index. But there is some strange behavior. When I click on first button it does not store index in state. Only after clicking on other buttons , it's starts saving , but wrong index. What could be the problem?

```
displayButtons() {
    const { data } = this.state
    let sortedButtons = data.map((items, idx) => {
      return (
        <Button
          key={idx}
          className="project-btn"
          primary
          onClick={() => this.setState({ index: idx })}
        >
          {items.title}
        </Button>
      )
    })
    return sortedButtons
  }

displayData() {
    const { data, index } = this.state
    let sortedData = data[index].settings.map((item, id) => {
      const { _init_ } = item.settings
      return _init_.map((message, index) => {
        const { message_content } = message

        return message_content === undefined ? null : (
          <div key={index}>
            <div>
              <div className="settings-message">{message_content}</div>
            </div>
            <div>yes</div>
          </div>
        )
      })
    })
    return sortedData
  }
```

Comment: Can you reproduce/provide your problem in a runnable SO snippet? Otherwise, can you at least provide the code of the whole component? We cannot help you if something else (like state initialization ;)) can have an impact but we can't see it.

Comment: Agree with @sjahan, it seems to me you just forgot to initialize your state in component constructor.

Comment: We need the state init and the place where you are actually doing `this.setState()` to change it, only then can we be of help.